# xcode : how should we display large number of Label & buttons in Tabular form?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

Actually I am having problem in displaying around 10-15 rows of Label & Button controls in view. Then I used UIScroll view to achieve this but that corrupt the appearance of design.

[image]

As you can see the generated output is different from the appearance in the Xcode while developing.

Please guid me what should be done to render proper design?

Thanks
Ashish

Comment: use label and button of exact size width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should use UITableView.
2. Create custom UITableViewCell.
3. Your each row will contain one UILabel and UIButton.
4. You can [check](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/).

See the attached image :

[image]

Comment: hi rushi, thanks for such swift reply. Can I create static Table view (I mean as the controls are fixed is there any approach that let me add controls directly in table view?), but thanks anyway I'll use your suggestion.

Comment: @AshishDiwakar static tableView as in? In your case you'll need dynamic tableview coz number of rows in label are not same. They are changing. To answer your question yes we can create static tableview.

Comment: can you provide Any link for static tableview.

Comment: Static as in your want every thing to be fixed?

Comment: @AshishDiwakar the tutorial link which I've given is creating a static tableview it self.

Comment: Well I have to display only 10 such rows & all are predefined. So I just want to know can we add cells in design or we need to achieve this by only coding.

Comment: See in this delegate method return 10. So your tableview will only create 10 rows. You can create UITableViewCell in storyboard also. - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom `UITableViewCell` and use that one in your code.

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` assign values to your cell properties.

Refer this Apple sample [code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913)

Also there are so many examples over net, search for custom `UITableViewCell` and you will find various tutorials out there.

Here is one more third-party tutorial [link](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/):

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks mrunal. is there any approach that let me add controls directly in table view in design mode?

Comment: No there are no such concept available. You will require to create one model for cell then you can reuse that cell in your tableview datasource method.